# Developing Carto Mobile App

Tags: android, maps, data-collection

I have the project to develop a mobile application (Android) being able to get offline maps, go on the field, collect datas about the area we're at and then synchronize it with our data server when we're back to the office.

This is for my end of study work (sry, don't know a best translation in english), and i looked at apps like gvSIG Mini, qGIS for Android, qmap, ..
But none of this really fits my need, as it is hardly adaptable ..

Any ideas on api/existing apps/anything ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. It might be easier to provide a useful answer if you can explain what (in as much detail as you can) was the problem with each of the applications you looked at. Alternatively, or as well, you might like to explain exactly what your new application needs to do.

Comment: Is there "ArcPad for Android" and if yes, is it any good?

Comment: I'm too :) I heard about QGIS API, but I did not found anything to use it on Android. Searching...